# viewDidLayoutSubviews equivalent for UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to update my cell after it obtain the proper size. Is there any equivalent of viewDidLayoutSubviews for UITableViewCell ?

Currently I'm adding a 0.1 delay to update the cell, but I think there should be a better approach.

```
   double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self layoutSubviews];
    });
```

Comment: call this two methods when you want to update the view. `setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: this works too. thanks! it's weird Apple don't just have a method that tells if it's done rendering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can try to override `UITableViewCell.layoutSubviews` method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.contentView layoutSubviews]; // this does the trick
}
```